# How to alert all content of page on button click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get all the content of page including all codes on `JavaScript` alert. Please check the code.

```js
function getContent() {
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName('html').value;
  alert(content);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  Some more code..........
  <a href="#" onclick="getContent()">Get Content</a>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to execute the function from inside the page and trying to get the value. It is giving me `undefined` error

Comment: Try with:
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)** returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements. You need to access the first index with `[0]`. In addition to this, it does not have a `.value` property. You're looking for **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** instead.

Note that you also shouldn't make use of `onclick`, and instead should make use of **[unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)** by **[adding an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function getContent() {
  var content = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
  alert(content);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].addEventListener('click', getContent);
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  Some more code..........
  <a href="#">Get Content</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: this will not work as expected in a Fiddle, but will work as expected on a proper website.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) field of a DOM element. Consider making the following changes to your `getContent()` function:

```js
function getContent() {
  var { innerHTML } = document.querySelector('html');
  alert(innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  Some more code..........
  <p> and some more content </p>
  <a href="#" onclick="getContent()">Get Content</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AkshayKapoor thanks - I assumed the OP wanted the text content based on the title of the post. I've updated the answer to obtain innerHTML :-)